# startx cannot open /dev/fb0: Permission denied

Tags: permissions, arch-linux, xorg, startx

When I try to start my WM using `startx`, I am unable to because the permission of something called `/dev/fb0` are restricted.

From `home/user/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log`:

```
[   198.569] (--) controlling tty is VT number 1, auto-enabling KeepTty
[   198.569] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[   198.569] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[   198.569] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[   198.570] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   198.570]    compiled for 1.16.0, module version = 0.0.2
[   198.570]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[   198.570] (EE) open /dev/fb0: Permission denied
[   198.570] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[   198.570] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[   198.570] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[   198.570] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[   198.570] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   198.570]    compiled for 1.16.0, module version = 0.0.2
[   198.570]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[   198.571] (EE) open /dev/fb0: Permission denied
```

Now of course I can change it using chmod, but I shouldn't have to do that every time I reboot the computer, so it seems like something is wrong / I haven't set up something properly.

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: [It's a consequence of the recent change to rootless X](https://github.com/archlinuxarm/PKGBUILDs/issues/926) (i.e. the X server doesn't run as root any longer). Looks like rootless X is not ready for prime time on Arch. You can arrange to get the permission to access `/dev/fb0`, but you should not have to (if you google, you'll find recommendations to add yourself to the `video` group… but that's propping the armored door open, it defeats the purpose).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Gilles [is correct](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149985/startx-cannot-open-dev-fb0-permission-denied#comment243856_149985); this is due to the changes in `xorg-server` 1.16 which were announced on the [Arch News](https://www.archlinux.org/news/xorg-server-116-is-now-available/).

To work around the permissions issue, you can use a Xorg.wrap config file to pass root rights, using:

```
needs_root_rights = yes
```

See `man Xorg.wrap` for the details.

You could also try using `xf86-video-modesetting` instead of `xf86-video-fbdev` until the fbdev driver is updated.

Comment: I have this same problem with Fedora but this solution doesn't help I have `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config` with `allowed_users=anybody` and `needs_root_rights=yes`. Any suggestions?

Comment: I second @Magpie's comment, even though  (not sure whether it matters) inserting a space before and after the "=" sign for each key-value pair in Xwrapper.config might help.  In my case, having `needs_root_rights = yes` generates  a few other errors, which weren't there to begin with, i.e. when only `(EE) open /dev/fb0: Permission denied` showed.