# How to change autologin from root to non-root user?

Tags: ubuntu, login, root, openbox, x-server

I have installed Ubuntu server 16.04(Actually it's `3.4.113-sun8i`
) with Openbox. and put this command `startx` inside `/etc/rc.local` to have graphics after boot. but the problem is that it automatically logins as root user, and because of this, my C++ program doesn't work correctly(As I asked before, they say it's because the root user can't start some libraries like pulseaudio or gtk automatically). And I think it's right because I should start them manually.

By the way, I am looking for a way that change autologin from root to non-root user. how can I do it?

> EDIT: my goal is building a gadget, users only can turn on/off it by
>   physical button(I mean no menu,option,etc). The gadget must execute my
>   C++ code after boot, and code uses gtk and pulseaudio libraries.

Comment: what you need is to boot to 'kiosk' mode. have a look at this -> https://thepcspy.com/read/converting-ubuntu-desktop-to-kiosk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You told me in [other comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/403599/my-ubuntu-server-doesnt-execute-my-gtk-based-program-at-startup/406384?noredirect=1#comment727316_406384) that your system shows this:

```
$ systemctl get-default
graphical.target
```

So, change it to `multi-user.target`:

```
$ sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

And multi-user.target will start at tty1 (Ctrl+Alt+F1):

```
$ systemctl list-dependencies multi-user.target | grep getty
● ├─getty.target
● │ ├─getty-static.service
● │ └─getty@tty1.service
```

So, we override tty1 file:

```
$ sudo systemctl edit getty@tty1
```

With this content (which `m` is your username):

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin m %I $TERM
```

`/sbin/agetty` above might different in your system, ensure your check the correct path with:

```
$ type -a agetty
agetty is /sbin/agetty
agetty is /sbin/agetty
```

Press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, then <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> to save and quit (this keys is for vim, you can run `ps a` in other terminal tab while edit to know its command is `editor /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/.#override.blahblah`, in which `editor` is symlink to `vim.gtk3` in my system, your system may vary).

```
$ type -a editor
editor is /usr/bin/editor
editor is /usr/bin/editor
$ realpath /usr/bin/editor 
/usr/bin/vim.gtk3
```

Then cat the `getty@tty1` and navigate to bottom, you will know it simply append this lines make override effect:

```
$ sudo systemctl cat getty@tty1 
 ...
# /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/override.conf
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin xiaobai %I $TERM
```

Auto login done by `--autologin` above, otherwise you need manually type username and password to login in tty1 after boot.

After loggedin to tty1 with username `m`, it will execute /home/m/.profile, so add this line at the end of your `/home/m/.profile`:

```
echo "$DISPLAY" > /tmp/hole1
echo "$XDG_VTNR" > /tmp/hole2
if [ -z "$DISPLAY" ] && [ -n "$XDG_VTNR" ] && [ "$XDG_VTNR" -eq 1 ]; then
  echo lolo > /tmp/hole3
  exec startx -- -nocursor
fi
echo lili > /tmp/hole4
```

`/tmp/holeN` above is for debug purpose only, in order to know it run as desired. e.g. If `/tmp/hole3` not created but `/tmp/hole2` was created, that's means you need to `cat /tmp/hole2` to check the value of "$XDG_VTNR" .

`startx` will then execute `/home/m/.xinitrc`, edit it:

```
$ cat /home/m/.xinitrc                                                                                                                             
#!/usr/bin/env bash                                                                                                                                   
echo 55 > /tmp/test1
exec openbox-session
echo 55 > /tmp/test2
```

`openbox-session` will then execute `/home/m/.config/openbox/autostart`, edit it as usual:

```
$ cat /home/m/.config/openbox/autostart 
echo 7 > /tmp/yy
/home/m/img &
echo 8 > /tmp/yy2
```

After all, reboot, will take you to shows your image directly, the instruction above can be summarized as:

> multi-user.target -> tty1 -> run getty@tty1.service ->  ExecStart
>   auto login with desired username -> logged-in will execute ~/.profile -> `exec startx` ->
>   startx will execute `~/.xinitrc` -> exec openbox-session -> openbox
>   will execute `~/.config/openbox/autostart` -> `/home/m/img &` will pop
>   up.

**[UPDATE]**

I chat with OP in [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69166/discussion-between--and-user145959) ([transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/69166)) and solved his problem.

rc.local able to startx because of rc.local run startx as root, but ~/.profile is not run startx as root. We do `startx > /tmp/my.log 2>&1` to ensure startx run correctly, then /tmp/my.log will shows we need to check `/home/m/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log`, and eventually I noticed the first `(EE)` is `(EE) open /dev/fb8: Permission denied`.

OP need to add user `m` to video group to obtain permission when startx to access desired FRAMEBUFFER /dev/fb8.

```
sudo usermod -a -G audio m
sudo usermod -a -G video m
```

[ref1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149985/startx-cannot-open-dev-fb0-permission-denied), [ref2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/924993/ubuntu-server-16-04-02-with-splash-screen-and-kiosk-mode/926596)

p/s: I wonder add to audio group above is necessary. [ref](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/TheAudioGroup)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69166/discussion-between--and-user145959).

Comment: I have a question. If I have a program that it needs to specify options to run, `./app -nmic yes` how can I change this line inside `/.configure/openbox/autostart` `/home/m/app &`

Comment: @user145959 `<app_full_path>  -nmic yes &` should work.

Comment: I have a program(`pocketsphinx`) that when I run it with command line, it shows it's results in terminal. but when I compile it and put it's executable inside`../openbox/autostart` I can not see anything in LCD and it seems program can't start terminal inside the LCD. Hoc can I fix this?

Comment: I mean if I have a console program, how to put it inside `autostart` file to shows terminal results?

Comment: @user145959 you can start your desired terminal emulator with program parameter which support run specific program on startup.

Comment: Before I see your answer I created a new question. may you answer there with more detail? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408522/how-to-start-a-console-program-at-startupinside-openbox-autostart

Comment: As my program is in this address `/home/m/test` I tried `gnome-terminal -- /home/m/test` but didn't work. I also tried `xterm -e /home/m/ttt
` but it opens a new terminal. It doesn't open my program. (my program prints please num1: after running)

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/rc.local` is executed as user `root`. You should thus use `su -l jdoe -c startx` in `rc.local`, assuming `jdoe` is the user you want to start Xorg.

I doubt you have systemd, because systemd, by default, ignores `rc.local` unless you upgraded from a prior version that did not have systemd and even then, not sure ... I don't run systemd.

If you do have systemd, you need to create a unit file for this. There are many resources online for this.

I searched google for "systemd unit file" and found the following:
Put the following in the file: `/etc/systemd/system/autologin.service` (assuming that is where systemd lives on your system)

```
[Unit]
Description=Autologin service

[Service]
Type=fork
user=jdoe
group=users
ExecStart=/path/to/your/startx
TimeoutSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You will have to adapt the unit, somewhat .... you probably do not want to start X as `jdoe` but as another user. Also, `users` might not be a group the user is a member of, last but not least, `/path/to/your/startx` is not the path to your `startx` ... run `which startx` to find out the path.

Next, you run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` to reload the configuration and reboot.

EDIT (following comments from op):

You want this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Autologin service

[Service]
Type=fork
user=m
group=m
ExecStart=/usr/bin/startx
TimeoutSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Assuming your `startx` is in `/usr/bin/startx`, that "should" work.

Comment: I have no /etc/x11 folder! My kernel is 3.4.113-sun8i. Also I have etc/xdg with openbox and systemd folders within.

Comment: may you give me some idea about what should I search about exactly?

Comment: Thank you for help! I have a question about user's group. I have only one non-root user named `m`, when I type `groups m` the result is `m: m`. So should I change that line in your code to `group=m` ?

Comment: Yup, user `m` is member of group `m` ... so you want `group=m`

Comment: Should I change the [Unit] too? change to what?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. Before this, when I put `startx` inside the `/etc/rc.local` after boot it was showing openbox window(a gray windows with a mouse pointer and right-click menu). But when I removed it from `rc.local` and did what you say above, now I have nothing! only a blank black screen.

Answer (score 0):

Start by removing `startx` from `/etc/rc.local`, then find out which display manager you have (most likely lightdm, since you're on Ubuntu).

Then read up on systemd services and display manager configuration, configure autologin on the display manager and enable its service.

Comment: I updated my question. Do you say I must do what you said yet?

Comment: I have no `/etc/x11` folder! My kernel is `3.4.113-sun8i`. Also I have `etc/xdg` with `openbox` and `systemd` folders within.