# How to start a console program at startup(inside ../openbox/autostart)

Tags: boot, startup, console, executable, display

I have a console program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
printf("please num1:");
int a;
cin>>a;
printf("please num2:");
int b;
cin>>b;
cout<<"see the result"<<endl;
return a+b;
}
```

With the executable named `test`. When I put this line:`/path/to/test test &` inside the `home/user/.config/openbox/autostart/` I can not see anything at startup, there is only a blank screen.

How can I see the terminal that runs this app at startup?
I should say I have tested the above method with the executable of other apps that show an image on LCD(using gtk+), or saying something in speaker(using espeak).They do these things att startup automatically. But for a console app this method doesn't work.I mean I can't see a terminal-shell at startup!

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: I tested `xterm -e /home/m/test` and no problem to see `please num1:`. I wonder how you compile your code, did you compiled your code in other machine and copy the program via `scp` OR compile the code in that openbox machine ? Also try `xterm -e xterm` which should open 2 terminals.

Comment: OHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH, you right!
The text was very small and I thought it's something like `m@nanopim1:~$ `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since your program is a **console** program and not a *graphical* one, as you stated and as your code shows
you need to launch it in a console, in a **terminal**. e.g.

```
gnome-terminal -- test.sh
```

in this case, I used gnome-terminal and the executable was *test.sh*.
this is the command to launch at startup

Comment: Thanks Mattia, but I use `openbox` and don't have `gnome` on my system(it's Ubuntu- Server with openbox installed on it). How should I change your code to openbox version?

Comment: Also, as I am new in Linux, my executable's name is `test`, why did you add `.sh` suffix?

Comment: @user145959 you can use (almost) any terminal e.g. xterm that is present in Ubuntu -> xterm -e /tmp/test.sh; test.sh is simply the name of my executable

Comment: As my program is in this addres `/home/m/test` I tried `gnome-terminal -- /home/m/test` but didn't work. I also tried `xterm -e /home/m/test` but it opens a new terminal. It doesn't open my program. (my program prints `please num1:` after running).

Comment: @user145959 does the executable file have the execute permission?

Comment: I don't know, how can I know?